# Hide menu items if the page content is empty

Tags: menus

i am looking for solution to hide (just not print) menu items if the page content is empty.

by default wordpress create menu item when new page created. and that ok.

but what i don't want, is when new page created, and the user still did not add any content to the page, is to show the page in the menu.

any suggestions?

Comment: I think page will never empty. Because every page have at-least default header and footer.

Comment: @HelpingHands you are right. but i want to check if the body content is empty and then to hide the menu item.

Comment: I think that is not feasible still not sure may be some one can help here. You can create custom menu to achieve your goal. If page have not content then you can delete that page from menu otherwise keep it.

Comment: In default themes, WordPress falls back to `wp_page_menu` if a nav menu isn't set up. The intention is for you to create a menu yourself so only pages you explicitly add show up in the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this, loop through all the `wp_nav_menu` items, get the post using the Object ID then test to see IF the content is empty. **IF** that content is empty then unset it from the items array:

```
function remove_empty_items( $items ) {
    $blog_page = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
    $home_page = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
    $postArr   = get_posts ( 'post_type=post' );

    foreach( $items as $key => $item ) {
        $tmpPost = get_post( $item->object_id );

        if( $item->object_id == $blog_page && empty( $postArr ) ) {
            unset( $items[$key] );
        } else if( $item->object_id !== $home_page && empty( $tmpPost->post_content ) ) {
            unset( $items[$key] );
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'remove_empty_items' );
```

Comment: Hi @Howdy_McGee yes thats help. Thanks! but i see another problem. i have page the show all posts(blog page) and this page dont removed from the loop if the user has not created any posts. so i can get this page by: $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ); but how i can check if there is no posts, remove the page?

Comment: @need-help You would have to run a small query just to check if there were any posts in that post type - I've updated my answer to reflect the comment.

Comment: Hi @Howdy_McGee i take your code and insert in funcastion.php and the website get white page. so somthing not working.

Comment: @need-help whoops, try that - `blog_post` wasn't a variable.

Comment: Hi @Howdy_McGee great the code works but with bug. it's also delete the home page from menu item. i have set some of the page as static page, and yes this page have body content. any suggestion?

Comment: @need-help did it do this before the blog conditional was added? I could just add another conditional to skip the homepage entirely ( always show the homepage ).

Comment: to be honest i don't remember. but now i see this. "always show the homepage" is good solution. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer, try that.

Comment: still the home page is not in the menu.

Comment: Not sure, I was able to get it to work on one my simple sites, one caveat is that if `$items` array is empty it will list all pages.

Comment: strange. i have content in the body and the code thing that this page content is empty or i dont know what else it can be. seems like it no skip the static home page

Comment: with the help of your code i have make some other code that fix the bug. but if you check your code and its work for you so for me i accept your answer. Thanks!